# Set MySQL conf in JDBC Input plugin in Logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I am using the `JDBC Input plugin` in `logstash` to index data based on `MySQL queries`.

I am able to successfully index data and get output, however, I am stuck at this.

One of my queries requires setting the `group_concat_max_len`. Is there a way to accommodate this in the input plugin itself? Because I want to avoid setting this at the global level.

I referred to [this site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-parameters) for different input parameters but nothing that solves my problem

Here is my sample input plugin:

```
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_connection_string=>"hostname"
        jdbc_user=>"user"
        jdbc_password=>"password"
        jdbc_driver_library=>"path/to/library"
        jdbc_driver_class=>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        lowercase_column_names => "false"
        statement_filepath => "query.sql"
    }

}
```

I also tried setting in the query.sql file, but looks like there should only one query be present.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You don't need to set it at the global level, but only the session level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605938/4604579

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the question. I was unaware of the fact that we can add `sessionVariables` parameter in the `connection string`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-compose, just set this variable in the container.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_USER=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    command: --group_concat_max_len=65535
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Check it in your database:
SELECT @@GLOBAL.group_concat_max_len;